# Concatenation of a string using ternary operator and recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion, ternary

I try to understand this one. It is an example from advanced javascript by John Resig.

```
function yell(n) {
    return n > 0 ? yell(n-1) + "a" : "hiy";
}
alert( yell(4) );
```

As a beginner I somehow would use a temporary variable to save the string and concatenate it to the final word (here hiyaaaa).

I cannot understand how this advanced example is working. Where the concatenation happens and how? Why is "hiy" before the "a"'s at the end, if it is added last?

Comment: It is recursion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's walk through this...

This is just a function declaration and nothing happens when it is reached (besides the function being parsed into memory):

```
function yell(n){
  return n > 0 ? yell(n-1) + "a" : "hiy";
}
```

Now, the function is invoked and the number `4` is passed into it:

```
alert( yell(4) );
```

The `4` is received as the value of the argument `n` and then this line:

```
  return n > 0 ? yell(n-1) + "a" : "hiy";
```

...first checks `n` to see if it is greater than `0`, which `4` is, so the `true` part of the ternary expression is carried out:

```
yell(n-1) + "a"
```

This makes a recursive call to `yell` and passes `3` (n - 1) to the function. Note that nothing is returned from the first call to `yell` yet, because flow control has been passed over to the second occurrence of `yell`.

The function runs again with `3` as `n` and again hits the `true` part of the ternary, causing the number to be reduced by one and then `yell` is called again.

This will continue until `yell` is recursively called with `0` as the value passed into it, at which time the `false` part of the ternary expression is invoked and `hiy` is returned and the `aaaa` from the recursive calls is concatenated onto that.

```js
function yell(n){
  return n > 0 ? yell(n-1) + "a" : "hiy";
}
alert( yell(4) );
```

Answer (score 6):

This is recursion. The *temporary variable* is the return value of the call to `yell`. `yell` calls itself until `n <= 0`. The easiest way to understand this may be to intuitively write out the series of calls that will be made to `yell`.

```
yell(4) == yell(3) + "a"
yell(3) == yell(2) + "a"
yell(2) == yell(1) + "a"
yell(1) == yell(0) + "a"
yell(0) == "hiy"
```

Substitute the values and you will get the final value for `yell(4)`.

The [Conditional Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) is just a terse way of expressing a conditional statement with two cases. By replacing this usage of the operator with the expand `if` statement form, it may be easier to conceptualize.

```
function yell(n) {
    if (n > 0) {
        return yell(n-1) + "a";
    }

    return "hiy";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The ternary is just a shortcut for an `if` statement:

```
function yell(n) {
    var temp;
    if (n > 0) {
        temp = yell(n-1) + "a";
    } else {
        temp = "hiy";
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Multiple concatenation is happening because the function calls itself recursively with a smaller value of `n`. The final call (when `n == 0`) returns `hiy`. When each recursive call returns, it appends `a` to the result and returns that back to the previous caller.

Answer (score 0):

```
function yell(n){
  if      (n > 3) {return yell(n-1) + "4"}
  else if (n > 2) {return yell(n-1) + "3"}
  else if (n > 1) {return yell(n-1) + "2"}
  else if (n > 0) {return yell(n-1) + "1"}
  else {return "0"} 
}
alert( yell(4) );
```

To see the order of each step of concatenation, I tried this.
Still confusing, but at least I see how it works.

Thank you all for the useful answers!

Comment: Glad to see you got it working! You should post these sort of things in the comments, unless you're actually answering your own question in a wiki style. We won't hurt you though! You'll get the hang of it.